# Restrict some first/initial value to be input in the textfield in Swift language

Tags: swift, textfield

Can someone please help me with my problem, the problem is that I want my first initial value that I enter into the textfield to be only number from 1 to 9, I am using Decimal pad so I also don't want my initial value to be a decimal point,but after the first value(only number from 1 t0 9) users are allowed to enter a only one decimal.I have done only one decimal thingy but cannot figure out how to let users not enter zero or decimal point as their initial/Starting value. please help me, Thank you in advance. I asked this before many said it is available online, but I cannot find it.If you upload the code it would mean the world to me.

Comment: Show your code for how you restricted it for one decimal and someone might suggest how you can extend that to handle the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, and you want to prohibit the user from entering a "." or "0" as the first character in the textField, then you need to set the textField's delegate to an instance of a class which contains this method:

`func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   if textField.text == "" && (replacementString == "0" || replacementString == ".") {
        return false
    }
    return true
}`

Comment: Jacek you just saved my life I don't know how to thank you. It is people like you make this world a better place. This problem has been bothering me for past   2 days and you solved it for me. I just can't thank you enough mate. I wish good for you sir and your family.